# A milestone achieved in ParticulEr

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

For I came after the forbidden.

Loved by the Italians  <3

Member of the Wilson's family

Swiftly came out way, a dozen before Christmas day.

Way more to say , but will not go the further way.

..

> beware for the curse can fall over you.

Hint

> I'm the sixth child of a world famous family.

Hint 2:

> Wilt Chamberlain has it but Michael Jordan doesn't, Alex Rodriguez has but Paul Goldschmidt doesn't and Pavel Datsyuk has but Ilya Kovalchuk doesn't ?

Hint 3:

> The title is also a hint.

Hint 4:

> Baker's Dozen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> Thirteen

For I came after the forbidden.

> 

Loved by the Italians <3

> In Italy 13 is considered a lucky number.

Member of the Wilson's family

> One of the Wilson primes

Swiftly came out way, a dozen before Christmas day.

> Twelve days before the 25 of December is the 13th of December

Beware for the curse can fall over you.

> 13 is considered sometimes as the unlucky number

Hint 1:

> Sixth prime number

Hint 2:

> Wilt Chamberlain, Alex Rodriguez and Pavel Datsyuk are all number 13 in their teams

Hint 3 :

> 

Hint 4 :

> But a baker’s dozen is commonly understood to mean 13.

Comment: Oh didn't see it. There is another box above. Thanks

Comment: Correct answer plus for line 1 it means that rot13(Gur Oevgvfu urnil zrgny cvbarref Oynpx Fnoongu'f yngrfg fghqvb nyohz vf ragvgyrq 13. Vg jnf eryrnfrq ba 11 Whar 2013 naq vg pnzr nsgre gur nyohz juvpu jnf anzrq sbevqqra). Plus as far as title is concerned rot13(gur qnl v cbfgrq guvf dhrfgvba Chmmyvat rkpunatr unq 13000 dhrfgvbaf nfxrq v.r. guvf jnf gur 13000gu dhrfgvba. Fb n zvyrfgbar npuvrirq va CR)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are

> Tom

For I came after the forbidden.

> Tom Riddle sought after immortality, via the Horcruxes.

Loved by the Italians <3

> Unsure on this one. Possibly a reference to the Italian mafia. Tommy Gun.

Member of the Wilson's family

> [Tom Wilson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wilson_Family)

Swiftly came out way, a dozen before Christmas day.

> 12 Drummers drumming, specifically on a [Tom-tom drum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom-tom_drum)

Way more to say , but will not go the further way.

> Thomas is typically the full name of someone named Tom. Also, possibly a reference to Thomas the Apostle (Doubting Thomas)

Title

> Unsure of right now, maybe the [Tommy Awards?](http://www.overture.org/programs/jerry-awards)

Hints

> Unsure

Comment: On the wrong track entirely.